# Can I use a data object as a scope in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

My app gets a json object from a server I want this very object to be the scope of my controller, that is without having to remap all its properties to the same properties of a scope. Us there a way to do that?

Comment: Look at `angular.extend`

Comment: The extend copies the properies, my question was about whether the original data object can be used as a scope.

Comment: Why do you want this anyway?

Comment: I am coming from knockout where we can use anything to be bound to the view. Having to remap everything to the scope looks like a overkill.

Comment: Show us some example. You just need to assign the data returned from remote server to a object defined on scope.

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to work the way you want it to even if you manage to hack it together so that angular accepts it as a scope. The scope [does more than just contain data](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope), it also contains the functionality (`scope.$watch()`, `scope.$apply()`, etc.) that is needed for basic angular operations like data-binding.

You could just store your data as a variable on the scope in your controller:

```
$scope.jsonData = JSON.parse(yourJSONData);
```

then instead of accessing it with `yourJSONData.someProperty` you would just use `$scope.jsonData.someProperty`. You won't have to remap any properties.

Adding one extra level of depth to your model is a lot less of a pain than recreating something like the `$apply` function (for example) on your own data object, which you would need to have defined in order for your model and view to communicate.